# Intersection of hyperplane in singular Point

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

I'm studying for my exam in Algebraic Geometry next week, and stumbled upon this problem:

Let $X$ be a variety, and $P \in X$ a nonsingular point. 
Suppose $H$ is some hyperplane, containing $P$ but not containing $X$. Then:
$$ \deg (X\cap H) = \deg(X) \deg(H) (= \deg(X)).$$
Any hints are appreciated. For me, the biggest problem is that I don't understand why we want $P$ to be non-singular.

Comment: I don't think nonsingularity is necessary, but it may make the problem slightly easier (since the intersection won't be "as bad").

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for your answer!